# Python - running select sections of code as sudo

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a script that can be run without root access, but if root access is required, a password can be collected, and select pieces of the code can be run as sudo? I could use the password and subprocess to run system commands one by one as root if necessary. However, I am using a library that was meant for scripts and requires each script to be run with root privileges. If I could just do something like

```
runAsRoot(blackBoxFunction, args)
```

I would be set. I really only have one block of code that I need root access for. I don't want to edit the entire library to fit my needs. I could do a workaround, where I generate a script and then execute the script as sudo using subprocess, but this seems prone to error and will be pain with how I set everything up, not to mention I might have to generate scripts on the fly have one great script that can handle every possible scenario.

Comment: This is an OS task, not a python issue. On Unix, an unprivileged process can only escalate its privileges by launching a separate, set-uid executable. So you can do what you want only by splitting your script into two programs. How they communicate is up to you.

Comment: or just force users to run your script as root ... hmmm i seem to remember  telling you this same thing a few days ago ... but meh tomato-tomahtoh ... maybe someone will be able to give you a different answer or phrase it for you in such a way that you accept it ...

Comment: Just remember that set-uid'ing a script doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way to almost get what you want

```
import inspect
import os
def sudo_call(fn,*args):
    with open("some_test.py","wb") as f:
        f.write(inspect.getsource(fn))
        f.write("%s(*%r)"%(fn.__name__,args)
    os.system("echo <SUDO_PASSWORD> | sudo -S -p '' python some_test.py ")

def hello(a,b):
    print a+b

sudo_call(hello,[1,2])
```

Comment: Is there any reason `os.system` is used over `subprocess`?

Comment: less letters to type ... if you use subprocess im not sure how well piping is supported you might have to do `proc.stdin.write(SUDO_PW)`