# run part of python script as sudo

Tags: python, security, subprocess, sudo

I'm trying to run only a part of my script `task.py` in `sudo` mode. Ideally I would run `task.py` with the following structure:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running normal parts')        
    .            .              .
    . [running normal commands] .
    .            .              .

    print('running sudo parts')
    .            .              .
    .  [running sudo commands]  .
    .            .              .
```

where I don't have to enter a password for the sudo parts of the script so that I can just make a single call `$ python task.py` from command line.

Is there a nice to tell Python to run the second block as `sudo`? I saw the `subprocess` module had a way to call a command with `sudo` privelages, but I'd rather not put the "sudo parts" into a separate script to do the "running sudo commands" part.

Comment: Possible dupes: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189165/python-running-select-sections-of-code-as-sudo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281235/how-do-you-temporary-run-your-code-as-root).

Comment: `sudo` won't run commands as root without having to type password, unless if you define a rule for that in `/etc/sudoers` to run a command as user or root without password. You need to be extra cautious with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ***highly*** recommend putting the `sudo` parts into a separate script just as the documentation recommended. That approach improves the security posture of your script dramatically as only the part necessary to execute with elevated privileges does (aka "least privilege"--a ***fundamental*** security principle).

I haven't read that documentation in detail, but I suspect it also mentions limiting write privileges to the `sudo` portion of the script as well and any file or resource that it may read from.